# How to assign unique ID for group of duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not asking how to delete duplicates.

I want to assign unique ID for group of duplicates:

```
A A
A A 
A B
B B
B B

A A 1
A A 1
A B 2
B B 3
B B 3
```

Comment: Show what you've tried. If you havn't tried anything and your asking for a place to look  'dense_rank'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by col1, col2) as newcol
from t;
```